# Flask jsonify: key starting with digit

Tags: python, json, flask, naming-conventions

Say i want to create the following JSON document in Flask:

```
{"1": {"name": "Tom"}}
```

I couldn't just call `return jsonify(**kwargs)`, because Python forbids naming variables starting with a number, like `1`.

Is it possible to create such a JSON document with Flask's `jsonify`? If not, what are my workarounds?

**Clarification:** I want to create a JSON document, which contains dicts indexed by ids, and ids have the form of 24 hexadecimal values ([ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/) from MongoDB). It means that most of the time ids will start with a digit.

Comment: Workarounds,   why are you outputting a 1?  do you want a jsonarray with jsonobject instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `flask.jsonify` takes the same parameters as Python's `dict`, you can give it a `dict` as a parameter and let it sort out the rest:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # note key is an int, not just a string with leading digits
    # in your case this could be a mongodb object
    return jsonify({1: {'name': 'bob'}})
```

Returns:

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "bob"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Conveniently, you can use... `**kwargs`!

```
>>> def echo(**kwargs):
...     print kwargs
...
>>> echo(**{"1":{"name": "Tom"}})
{'1': {'name': 'Tom'}}
```

Yes, you can't manually specify an individual keyword argument named `1`... but you *can* pass a keyword argument named `1` via the `**` keyword expansion operator.